# Validate 2 forms using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

On my MVC project I have a View with 2 forms.

I validate the forms using jquery validation.

How can I validate 2 forms on submit of one of them?

I tried that:

```
$(function () {
     $("#form1").validate();
     $("#form2").validate();
     $.extend($.validator.messages, { required: "*", email: "Invalid email address." })
});
```

But only the second form gets validate but the first one don't, any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: @mplungjan How this question is a duplicate of the one you referred to? I'm talking about 2 forms? !!

Comment: Because: `$("#form1").on("submit",function(e) { if ($("#form1").valid() && $("#form2").valid()) { console.log("great job");  else e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: This is an answer to my question, not a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: If you know how to test ONE form is valid, you know how to test TWO forms are valid!

Comment: The way I used to validate the form is different than the one that you suggested and when I'm (or someone else) looking for a solution to this kind of issue, I won't get to the question you referred to. I do think that my question and your answer can be very helpful for others.

Comment: By all means... Be my guest :)

Comment: @mplungjan Sure! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#form1").on("submit",function(e) { 
  if ($("#form1").valid() && $("#form2").valid()) { 
    console.log("great job"); 
  else e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

For alternatives

[Validating multiple forms on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941338/validating-multiple-forms-on-the-same-page)